# Does there exist an arbitrarily large bipartite graph that is critical of dimension 4?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry

Here's a question in geometric graph theory that I recently kicked the tires on but was unable to resolve.

For a finite, simple graph $G$, say that $G$ is of dimension $n$, and write $\dim(G) = n$, if $n$ is the smallest integer such that $G$ can be drawn as a unit-distance graph in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Define $G$ to be *dimension-critical* if $\dim(G') < \dim(G)$ for any proper subgraph $G'$ of $G$.  It is known that any bipartite graph $G$ has $\dim(G) \leq 4$, with examples of this upper bound being given by complete bipartite graphs of the form $G = K_{r,s}$ where $r,s \geq 3$.

My question is this:

*Does there exist an arbitrarily large bipartite graph $G$ that is dimension-critical and has $\dim(G) = 4$?*

Even if a full resolution is not given for the above question, I'd be happy to see some examples of a $K_{3,3}$-free bipartite graph of dimension 4, should such a thing exist.

Comment: What are the largest critical 4-dimensional bipartite graphs you know of?

Comment: Other than $K_{3,3}$, I can't guarantee the existence of any critical 4-dimensional bipartite graphs.  One seemingly likely candidate that I considered is $K_{5,5}$ minus a 1-factor.  Ultimately, however, I could find neither a unit-distance representation of this graph in $\mathbb{R}^3$ nor a proof that no such representation is possible.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but can't any bipartite graph be embedded into $\Bbb R^1$ with unit distance. Just put all vertices in the one partition class at $1$, and the others at $0$. Or do we need that the vertices are mapped to distinct points?

Comment: I should have been more clear on that.  In all cases, the vertices of the graph must be distinct points of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I think it may be useful to have a characterization of bipartite graphs of dimension 2. Is that available?

Comment: @Luca: I doubt an all-purpose characterization exists describing bipartite graphs $G$ with $\dim(G) = 2$.  It's immediate that any such example cannot have $K_{2,3}$ as a subgraph, but that alone isn't sufficient.  Consider $G$ formed by starting with two disjoint paths on $n$ vertices for odd $n \geq 5$, with those vertices labeled $a_1, ..., a_n$ and $b_1, ..., b_n$.  Place edges $a_ib_i$ for $i = 1, ..., n$ along with the additional edges $a_1b_n$ and $a_nb_1$.  It turns out that $\dim(G)=3$, and incidentally, this graph is what I used to answer the posted question in the case of $n=3$.